# Which other units should I use with my hero in a raid for maximum effectiveness?

Tags: clash-of-clans

The introduction of heroes to the game adds several new elements to consider strategically.  It seems that when they are used correctly, they can really tear the place up, but when raiding I often see my hero get overwhelmed in a matter of seconds, by defenses I think he should beat.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Though I did self answer, I am interested in other answers to this question.  Please add an answer if you have a strategy that has worked for (or against) you.  I'm also interested in effective use of the Archer Queen, or two hero strategies - since I've not seen them used together yet.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend high hitting troops such as wizards, P.E.K.K.A's, or dragons. Also healers can heal your barbarian king and with 2-3 of them your hero would be invincible so to speak. If you use giants to take out defences then the barbarian king will take out mines, pumps, storages, and other non- attacking towers.

Answer (score 0):

Heroes have a couple nuances to consider, and I haven't fully figured them out myself yet - but here are some tips.

- Try to pave a path before deploying your hero.  He/She will attack anything in sight, and may waste time and hitpoints attacking walls and non-premium buildings if they are not clear.
- Remember to make use of spells.  Lightning can help make a hole in walls, or weaken tough defenses.  Heal can prop up your hero in a tough fight.  **Above all I highly recommend Rage**, which will greatly increase your heroes damage.
- Use a healer.  They take up a lot of space and are expensive, but with unlimited heals it is actually possible to leave the fight ***with your hero at full health!***  This means he/she can be back in action with no wait time, which is a huge benefit.